# Доступ к некоторым элементам JSON-объекта

Tags: javascript, json

Есть JSON следующего вида:

```
{"0":["149","15","17"],"1":["249","20","22"],"2":["349","25","27"],"3":["249","20","22"],"bagage":"200","animals":"200","baby":"100","help":"200","HelloYobaEtoTy":"100"}
```

Столкнулся с проблемой получения доступа к некоторым его элементам.

К примеру `alert(js.bagage);` отрабатывает нормально.

А вот как получить доступ к нумерованным элементам?

Следующий вариант 
`if ("1" in json){ alert("isset");}` отрабатывает нормально. Но вот вызвать его напрямую, т.е.:

`alert(js.1);`

Не удастся. Как можно все таки получить доступ к таким элементам json?

Comment: Попробуйте вот так: console.log(js['0']);

Comment: @VladVetrov, о как, получилось. Спасибо. Оформите в ответ, приму как правильный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var js ={"0":["149","15","17"],"1":["249","20","22"],"2":["349","25","27"],"3":["249","20","22"],"bagage":"200","animals":"200","baby":"100","help":"200","HelloYobaEtoTy":"100"}

console.log(js.baby);
console.log(js['0']);
console.log(js['0'][0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя обратиться к числовому индексу через точку. Используйте квадратные скобки.

```
js[1] // (3) ["249", "20", "22"]
```